# Multiple Click Incrementation

Tags: vb.net

I am incrementing a variable (+1) everytime a `PictureBox` gets clicked but the count is stuck at 1, not going to 2 or 3 or 4 everytime the `PictureBox` is clicked.

```
    Dim AddIncrement As Integer
    AddIncrement = AddIncrement + 1
    Dim Menu As String = AddIncrement
    TextBox1.Text = Menu
```

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On` and more than likely your variable is not at the correct level, declare it outside so it retains the value everytime you add to it. Also you're not adding to a picturebox, perhaps a type-o?

Comment: Just declare the variable outside the method. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is inside a method, right? With a signature that looks something like this:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
```

This may not be 100% exact, but it should be close. So what you really have looks more like this:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click  
    Dim AddIncrement As Integer
    AddIncrement = AddIncrement + 1
    Dim Menu As String = AddIncrement
    TextBox1.Text = Menu
End Sub
```

Now we need to look at the `AddIncrement` variable. The `Dim` statement for this variable is *inside the method*. That is, it is redefined every time the method runs. Each method call is actually working with a *different variable*.

To fix it, move the variable declaration outside the method, to be at the Class/Module level:

```
Private AddIncrement As Integer = 0
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click  
    AddIncrement += 1
    TextBox1.Text = AddIncrement.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: Could also look at using `Static`.

Comment: `Static` is looked down on by OOP purist as a leftover from vb 6. Also the C# community probably doesn't like it because I don't think they have it. I think it is very tidy way to approach maintaining state for a variable that is only used in the current method.